# WYSIWYG Editor for TWIKI

Tags: text-editor, wysiwyg, twiki

i'm searching for an WYSIWYG Editor tool which i can run as normal Windows Application and wihich generates for me the TWIKI "Code".

Is there any Application/Software that provides this functionality?

THX

Answer (score 2):

not that I know of - though there have been some development wrt using WebDAV and saving from HTML - talk to Crawford Currie - the main developer of both those addons to twiki/foswiki